# What is Wrong with my Jquery Autocomplete Code Below?

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                debugger;
                var availableTags = ("ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme");

                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="tags" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfkt4/9/) link to it, works fine on Fiddle, but not from VS

Comment: Woah, that code is out of this world!

Comment: got it from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ not workkin when I run from VS !

Comment: If you have got your answer than atleast accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the code you are using from VS is not the same as the fiddle version.

The fiddle code looks perfectly fine, but the code you posted here has a syntax error. You must use square brackets to create an array, not parentheses:

```
var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", ... ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a doctype to your HTML file. Some browsers don't run javascript if there is no proper Doctype given.